# Index creation leads to large transaction log growth

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014, transaction-log

I have an approximately 1 billion row table. I then create an index as follows:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Index1] 
ON [dbo].[MyTable]( [CustomerID] ASC )  -- CustomerID is uniqueidentifier
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE);
```

This results in a 9.15GB index (compressed), however the transaction log went from empty to 158GB while the index was being created (no other DB activity). **Why is the amount of log space used that much higher than the resulting size of the index?**

The database is SQLServer 2014 Enterprise in full recovery mode in an availability group.

**Update**
I dropped and recreated the index with the option `SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON`. The resulting transaction log writes were 10.4GB for the DB's tlog and 1.27GB for the tempdb tlog.

Comment: Have you considered temporarily changing the recovery model to BULK_LOGGED during the index create to mitigate log usage and improve index create performance?

Comment: The tlog autogrowth must be set to a % increase as opposed to fixed MB value. % increment is like compound interest.

Comment: @DanGuzman yes, we are looking at that. Currently we can't drop below full recovery because we're in an AG. We'd need to drop the AG, do our index builds and recreate the AG.

Comment: @Kin this is not about the size of the tlog (which is pre-sized), but the amount of tlog that is used compared to the resulting size of the index. I'm assuming this is probably due to the tlog being uncompressed or something like that.

Comment: I am curious if the page compression is affecting this as well? Anyone have thoughts on that? Or did you try creating the index without compression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referring to MS documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188281(v=sql.120).aspx). Also [Creating a 60GB Index](http://sqlfool.com/2009/01/creating-a-60-gb-index/) on SQLFool.

What I believe is happening is that when the index is being built with `SORT_IN_TEMDB=OFF`, the entire index build processed is logged via the DB's transaction log (DB is set to full recovery). (In addition, I expect there to be a high number of page splits due to the scattergun-nature of the GUID column that is being indexed)

When the index is built using `SORT_IN_TEMPDB=ON`, then most of the transaction log activity is going to be against `tempdb` which is in `SIMPLE` recovery mode.